# C++ Изменение char* внутри функции вызывает ошибку

Tags: c++, строки, память

Есть функция:

```
char* find_markers(char* haystack, char* marker_opening, char* marker_closing, char* &contents, char* &after)
{
    // ...<marker1>... ... ...<marker2>...
    //    ^return  ^contents  ^NULL    ^after

    char* marker_begin = strstr(haystack, marker_opening);
    if(marker_begin)
    {
        contents = &marker_begin[strlen(marker_opening)];

        char* marker_end = strstr(contents, marker_closing);
        if(marker_end)
        {
            haystack[marker_end-haystack] = NULL;
            after = &marker_end[strlen(marker_closing)];
            return marker_begin;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Смысл которой в том, чтобы искать в тексте пару тегов, возвращать ссылки на начало, окончание, и содержимое тега. При этом функция заменяет конец содержимого на NULL-byte, чтобы сделать его нормальной строкой.

Код тестовой программы:

```
int main()
{

    char* text = "            <tag>contents1</tag>       <tag><tag>           ";
    char* cursor = text;
    char* contents = NULL;

    while(true)
    {
        if(!find_markers(cursor, "<tag>", "</tag>", contents, cursor)) break;
        cout << contents << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вылетает с результатом: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
На строке: haystack[marker_end-haystack] = NULL;

Как это полечить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала - запомнить, что в С++ строковый литерал менять нельзя. Это - константная строка, которая может находиться в read-only памяти. А вы в нее пытаетесь что-то писать. Как минимум UB - и в результате все, что угодно. Кстати, неужели вам компилятор об этом не ругался?

Ну, а минимальное исправление - передавать не литерал, а массив символов.

Изменить сигнатуру функции на

```
char* find_markers(char* haystack, const char* marker_opening, 
                   const char* marker_closing, char* &contents, char* &after)
```

а вызов -

```
char text[] = "            <tag>contents1</tag>       <tag><tag>           ";
```

Так вы делаете *изменяемую копию* строки. Полный текст - https://ideone.com/RNurNc

Да, и еще - раз уж у вас С++, почему бы не работать со средствами С++? Строками `string`, например?

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!